# How do you log in with face id on react native with firebase?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native

I'm seeing limited information online regarding this subject.

How do you log in with faceid on react native and firebase? there's obviously this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics I can use

I can use that api to potentially generate the face id log in but then how or what would I send to firebase on the backend to confirm the user is who they say they are or grab the necessary details etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the biometrics package along with secure storage, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-secure-storage

You store the user name and password in the secure storage, and use the stored credential to login the user once biometrics is successful.

Comment: Hi Wen, have you got example of how this would work?

Comment: the link below has a pretty good example. instead of using secure storage, asyncstorage was used. It's the same concept tho. https://medium.com/swlh/integrate-biometric-authentication-to-your-expo-app-77252d041f5